# How can i set up the ssh to my computer for github?

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh, key

I have tried to set up my ssh with this [tutorial](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) but not work I always have the same error. How i can set up it?

I have these keys:

```
user@LAPTOP-LC8KG6GU MINGW64 ~/Documents/programmi_prove/helloworld_project (master)
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197609    0 giu 17 16:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197609    0 giu 17 17:13 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197609 3389 giu 17 23:12 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197609  748 giu 17 23:12 id_rsa.pub
```

These are my errors:

```
user@LAPTOP-LC8KG6GU MINGW64 ~/Documents/programmi_prove/helloworld_project (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

user@LAPTOP-LC8KG6GU MINGW64 ~/Documents/programmi_prove/helloworld_project (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git/
fatal: remote origin already exists.

user@LAPTOP-LC8KG6GU MINGW64 ~/Documents/programmi_prove/helloworld_project (master)
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git/' not found
```

Comment: what's the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: this is the output for "git remote -v":                    
*     origin  https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git (fetch)
*     origin  https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git (push)

Comment: try this `git branch --set-upstream <remote-branch>`, then `git push`, what are you getting? One thing I've noticed, is there is an extra `/` at the end of your remote url, `..... firstapp.git/` make sure you're pointing to the correct URL

Comment: @WilliamKinaan with "git branch --set-upstream-to  https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git", I have this:
error: the requested upstream branch 'https://github.com/speranza493/firstapp.git' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.

Comment: you executed a wrong command. Assuming you at in `master` branch Please try `git branch --set-upstream origin master`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I have used it because "git branch --set-upstream origin master" doesn't work: git branch --set-upstream origin master
fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did your repo url change? use `git remote rm origin` to remove the remote and then readd it with `git remote add origin YOURURLHERE`

Comment: I have done it but it makes the same mistake as before. The url that I use I copy from github

Comment: @MarcoSperanza Is it a private repo? I tried following your url and the page doesn't exist.